# I have a problem when dealing with the local database when adding and modifying

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a problem when editing and adding the database

I tried to edit and search for the problem but could not find the solution

```
   public boolean insert_dealer(get_set_db dealer){

        ContentValues Values = new ContentValues();
       Values.put(My_data.dealer_CLN_NMEA  , dealer.getName());
       Values.put(My_data.dealer_CLN_description , dealer.getDescribe());
       Values.put(My_data.dealer_CLN_image , dealer.getImage());
       Values.put(My_data.dealer_CLN_WHOLESALE , dealer.getWholesale());
       Values.put(My_data.dealer_CLN_INDIVIDUAL , dealer.getAn_individual());

       long result = database.insert(My_data.dealer_TB_NAME,null,Values);
       return result != -1;
   }
```

Logs details

```
2019-07-11 09:28:44.341 31418-31418/com.example.dealer E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "individual": syntax error
2019-07-11 09:28:44.348 31418-31418/com.example.dealer E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting image=kcc An individual=3.0 describe=othman wholesale=2.0 Name=ott
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "individual": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO dealerr(image,An individual,describe,wholesale,Name) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:903)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:514)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1562)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1433)
        at com.example.dealer.DatabaseAccess.insert_dealer(DatabaseAccess.java:49)
        at com.example.dealer.Main2Activity.onOptionsItemSelected(Main2Activity.java:154)
```

Comment: what is value of  `My_data.dealer_CLN_INDIVIDUAL `?

Answer (score 0):

Here dealer.getAn_CLN_INDIVIDUAL() returning "An individual", here you can not keep an attribute name with space. Just change it to an_individual, hope it will work.

```
My_data.dealer_CLN_INDIVIDUAL , dealer.getAn_individual()
```

Answer (score 0):

The constant `My_data.dealer_CLN_INDIVIDUAL` which represents a column's name, has been defined as:

```
String dealer_CLN_INDIVIDUAL = "An individual";
```

A column's name must not contain spaces.
You can enclose it in square brackets to solve the problem:

```
String dealer_CLN_INDIVIDUAL = "[An individual]";
```

Comment: @OthmanHamada if this answer solved your problem consider accepting it by clicking at the checkmark.